# QGIS Set Master Password

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, authentication, server

I installed a fresh version of the QGIS LTR 3.10. I am working on creating a postgres server from a raspberry pi4 and connecting the database to my qgis. Through a tutorial I am walking through, they suggest creating a Basic Authentication configuration (image 1). I type in a username and password, click the `convert to configuration` button and I receive a box asking for the current master password (image 2). I've tried researching how to find this and have only come across opening the qgis-auth.db file. I've opened it with a text editor, but its mainly a bunch of symbols that don't make sense to me. So I am wondering how/where do I set up this master password?

[image]
[image]

Comment: See the really well documented official documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_overview.html?highlight=master%20password#master-password

Comment: you will also need to use the ip address of the raspberry pi to access the postgres database.you may also need to allow your client (pc) to access the raspberry postgres server https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thanks I will take a look at that!

Comment: @Mapperz Yes I have been using the ip address of the raspberry pi. I can access the database, but if I want to create a basic authentication, that is when the `Enter Credentials` pops up.